# 'correct' semantics for ftell() when used on a memory stream

Tags: c, posix, stdio, ftell

Can anyone explain the 'correct' semantics for ftell() when used on a memory stream.

Given the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

int main(void)
{
   puts (gnu_get_libc_version ());

   size_t n_buffer = 1024;
   char *buffer = calloc(n_buffer, sizeof(char));
   FILE *file = fmemopen(buffer, n_buffer, "w");

   /* "ABCD" */
   static const char magic_number[] = 
   {
     0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 
   };

   const size_t written = fwrite(magic_number, 1, 4, file);
   fprintf(stderr,"written=%d\n",written);

   int fstatus = fflush(file);
   fprintf(stderr,"fstatus=%d\n",fstatus);

   long ftellpos = ftell(file);
   fprintf(stderr,"ftellpos=%ld\n",ftellpos);

   fstatus = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
   fprintf(stderr,"fstatus=%d\n",fstatus);

   ftellpos = ftell(file);
   fprintf(stderr,"ftellpos2=%ld\n",ftellpos);

   return 0;
}
```

The output on RHEL7 is:

```
2.17
written=4
fstatus=0
ftellpos=4
fstatus=0
ftellpos2=4
```

Whereas the output on OpenSUSE Leap 42 is:

```
2.22
written=4
fstatus=0
ftellpos=0
fstatus=0
ftellpos2=4
```

(This led to a unit test failure in code I was looking at)

My questions are:

- Is the fseek() required (by a standard) to make the result of ftell() valid?
- Is this a bug or change in behaviour of glibc?
- Why doesn't it work on OpenSUSE?

The most obvious implementation is for the *file position indicator* to be
an index in the memory buffer given to fmemopen. 
Its hard to see how that could go wrong.

Indeed the implementation:

https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/73dfd088936b9237599e4ab737c7ae2ea7d710e1/libio/fmemopen.c

Has c->pos = pos + s; at line 85.

And presumably ftell() just returns c->pos (in a roundabout way)

There has been some re-organisation of the glibc source source between 2.17 and 2.22 
that would probably explain this if I could unravel it.
But is it a bug or feature?

I'm not sure if the Posix and C standards fully specify whether ftell
should work correctly for a memory stream.
Intuitively its hard to see why it shouldn't be mandated as it
ought to just work.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html

Says:

"The current position is implicitly updated by I/O operations. 
It can be explicitly updated using fseek(3), and determined using ftell(3)."

Other man pages mention that ftell might not have to work
for things that aren't really files. 
However, I believe they really have devices in mind there.

Comment: So, what does the only authoritative resource about **standard** functions tell you?

Comment: Sounds like a bug - [file one here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=glibc)

Comment: Although unlikely the issue, the casual integer type conversion done here add unnecessary questions to the post.  Suggest to use the right type and print specifiers.  `ftell()` returns `long` and `size_t` needs a `"zu"`.

Comment: @Olaf there are two authorative sources C and Posix. I believe both leave it undefined but I am not a language lawyer. Hence my question.

Comment: @o11c I believe you are correct. It is either a bug in the implementation (my belief) or a bug in the documentation or both.
I've submitted a bug report here:
  https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22140 
Lets see what the maintainers have to say.

Comment: There may also be a linked bug in the Posix specification itself http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1156

Comment: "there are two authorative sources C and Posix" - No. POSIX refers to ISO9899 . Hence it inherits the C standard. And that one **is** clear (unless you forgot relevant info in the question). Read it, details are important.

Comment: Memory streams are part of Posix not C. The C standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf does not say much about ftell() except to warn about the difference between binary and text files.
If you think it is clear then please explain.
Likewise http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html discusses seek behaviour but not ftell.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this quote on the net in a discussion:

*The ftell() Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 doc states ‘ftell() shall return the current value of the file-position indicator for the stream.’  The file position indicator is not updated without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), or until the buffer is full.*

So, it looks like there is some buffer handling difference in rh and suse. You would need to flush the buffer in a way to read the correct position in the file.

Comment: I am well aware of that requirement. Note that there is a call to fflush after the write in my original example.

Comment: "I found this somewhere in the mud" is not really a good start for an answer. That does not answer if it is allowed to do or not (it is).

Comment: @Olaf yes, i know, but it points to a doc and explains the behavior.

Comment: I don't see any "pointer" And it is wrong/missleading, too. Read the standard instead of obscure forums!

Comment: @Olaf you are welcome to provide a quote from a standard. please to it.

Comment: How about you read 7.21.9.4 yourself? I'm not for spoon-feeding; own research will gain knowledge much more easily and anchor it better in the brain..

Comment: @Olaf for your information, there is absolutely nothing in the standard which would shed any light on the behavior of the ftell function as in the original question.

Comment: "the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read". And `ftell` returns a `long int`, not an `int`. Actually the compiler should emit a truncation warning, at least for 64 bit Linux.